# Move object into data structure without creating two objects

Tags: c++

I create an object, for example:

```
std::string s{"string"};
```

And I want to add that object into a data structure (let's say an std::vector) without taking up the memory space for two objects.

When I do this:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
vec.emplace_back(std::move(s));

std::cout<<"s = "<<s<<"\n";
std::cout<<"vec[0] = "<<vec[0]<<"\n";

s = "different string";

std::cout<<"\ns = "<<s<<"\n";
std::cout<<"vec[0] = "<<vec[0]<<"\n";
```

I get this output:

```
s = 
vec[0] = string

s = different string
vec[0] = string
```

So yes it "erased" the data in the original string, but if I'm able to assign it new values, that means the object still exists, and if the object still exists, doesn't that mean that the program is keeping enough space in memory for both objects and all of their member variables?

Even if I create the string as an rvalue, as shown below, I believe it's calling the constructor, moving it, and then calling the destructor, meaning that there were two objects in memory at one point.

```
vec.emplace_back("string");
```

Basically I'm wondering, what's the most efficient way to get an object into a data structure?

Comment: *it's calling the constructor, moving it, and then calling the destructor* This is wrong belief. It does not move nor call the destructor.

Comment: It is pretty fundamental to C++ that all variables _exist_.  If it were possible to have variables that don't exist, tracking whether a variable exists would require memory to do so, defeating your purpose.  Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm sorry for my naiveté, I'm simply asking the most efficient way to get an object into a data structure.

Comment: @WaddleDee72 You may want to [edit] your question then.  Currently, it does not ask that question.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed it.

Comment: @WaddleDee72: Why are you concerned with the 32 bytes (give or take) the emptied `std::string` object consumes for whatever tiny amount of time is left until the function performing this work returns? It's not reserving some variable amount of memory or holding onto heap memory, the memory here is on the stack (which grows and shrinks all the time, so the memory is constantly reused), it just doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm just trying to better understand the mechanics of C++ and grow as a developer. `std::string` was just an example—I could be copying an instance of a class that takes up more space.

Comment: @WaddleDee72: As a rule, class instances *don't* take up meaningful space. `std::array` is a notable exception, but aside from that, and terrible toy classes using embedded arrays that people only write when they're new and learning how this stuff works, you generally store bulk data outside the class instance itself. If you don't, instances of your class on the stack are *dangerous* (you can blow stack memory by allocating even relatively small arrays of them), and it makes move semantics less useful (because so much work must be done to perform the move). You just don't do it in real code.

Comment: "*Even if I create the string as an rvalue, I believe it's calling the constructor, moving it, and then calling the destructor, meaning that there were two objects in memory at one point*" - that would be true if you had used `push_back()`, but the whole point of `emplace_back()` is to avoid that. It will create only 1 object directly in the vector's data array, passing your input to that object's constructor. You are passing in a string literal, not a string object.

Answer (score 1):

You're sort of right and sort of wrong.

Since you used `string`, let's consider a simple implementation of string:

```cpp
class string {
    char *data;
    unsigned currentLength;
    unsigned allocationSize;

    // a lot more complexity we don't care about for now elided here
};
```

So, the string object itself just stores the current length of the string, the amount of space allocated, and a pointer to storage for the string itself.

When you do something like `a = std::move(b);` it copies those sizes and that pointer from `b` to `a`, then sets the ones in `b` to indicate that it's empty. So you do temporarily have two string *objects*, but you *don't* have a duplicate of the string data itself. So if you had a string that was (say) 20 megabytes long, that assignment would not require 40 megabytes of memory at any time. The string object might occupy 24 bytes, in which case before the assignment you'd have 20 megabytes + 24 bytes, during it you'd have 20 megabytes + 48 bytes, and after `b` was destroyed, you'd be back to 20 megabytes + 24 bytes.

There is one other wrinkle though. Most implementations of `std::string` have what's called a "small string optimization". A lot of strings are quite short, and having 24 bytes to keep track of it + a block of memory on the heap to store the string itself isn't very efficient.

A typical current processor uses a 64-bit type for a pointer, but it really only supports up to something like 42 bit addressing (or so--varies between processors).

In most cases, we can use (for example) a special value in one byte of that pointer to signify that it's not really a pointer. Instead, we do something like:

```cpp
class internalString {
    // some value that can't be here in a pointer:
     char const magic = 0x2b;
     char data[23];
};

class externalString {
    // same as the string shown previously
};

union string {
    internalString internal;
    externalString external;
};
```

From there, we look at that first byte, and see if it's the "magic" value to signify an internal string. If it is, then we treat it as an `internalString`, that stores the data inside the string object itself.

In this case, an `std::move` doesn't really accomplish a whole lot. Moving data from one string to another still involves copying the data from one to the other, and during the move we have two string objects occupying twice the space of one string object. But it only happens when the string is small, so we usually don't care much.

#### Disclaimer

Just in case I wasn't clear about it previously, I'm simplifying things quite a lot here. Possibly a little too much. But hopefully just enough so it's easy to grasp the points at hand.

Comment: Ah I see. So the efficiency partially depends on the implementation of the class that you are inserting into the data structure.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But also note that emplace back supports not passing the actual object to be inserted at all, but instead passing the parameters that will be forwarded to the ctor to construct the object in place. For example, if you had a `std::vector<std::string>`, and you wanted to emplace a string of 1 million "A"s, you could do `myVector.emplace_back(1'000'000, 'A');`, and the *only* string object that size would be the one created in the vector itself.